# Build Apk of JS Application

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I Try To Build An Android App with JS
I Want To Build An Apk Of My HTML , CSS , JS Apllication
How Can I do ?
Note : i want Apk File For Android App Stores Not Only Mine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a native way you should look at: [Building Web Apps in WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

For a framework way of building it look at: 
Apache Cordova: http://cordova.apache.org

or Phone gap: http://phonegap.com